# string to bufferstream not always writing data

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a cloud function receiving a json string in a pubsub topic.
The goal is to extracts some data into a new json string.
Next parse it as JSONL.
And finally stream it to Google Cloud Storage.

I notice that sometimes the files seem to contain data and sometimes they do not.
The pubsub is working fine and data is coming into this cloud function just fine.

I tried adding some async awaits where I seem it might fit but I am afraid it has do to with the bufferstream. Both topics on where I have trouble getting my head around.

What could be the issue?

[image]

```
const stream = require('stream');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Initiate the source
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

// save stream to bucket
const toBucket = (message, filename) => {
  // Write your buffer
  bufferStream.end(Buffer.from(message));

  const myBucket = storage.bucket(process.env.BUCKET);
  const file = myBucket.file(filename);
  // Pipe the 'bufferStream' into a 'file.createWriteStream' method.
  bufferStream.pipe(file.createWriteStream({
    validation: 'md5',
  }))
    .on('error', (err) => { console.error(err); })
    .on('finish', () => {
      // The file upload is complete.
      console.log(`${filename} is uploaded`);
    });
};

// extract correct fields
const extract = (entry) => ({
  id: entry.id,
  status: entry.status,
  date_created: entry.date_created,
  discount_total: entry.discount_total,
  discount_tax: entry.discount_tax,
  shipping_total: entry.shipping_total,
  shipping_tax: entry.shipping_tax,
  total: entry.total,
  total_tax: entry.total_tax,
  customer_id: entry.customer_id,
  payment_method: entry.payment_method,
  payment_method_title: entry.payment_method_title,
  transaction_id: entry.transaction_id,
  date_completed: entry.date_completed,
  billing_city: entry.billing.city,
  billing_state: entry.billing.state,
  billing_postcode: entry.billing.postcode,
  coupon_lines_id: entry.coupon_lines.id,
  coupon_lines_code: entry.coupon_lines.code,
  coupon_lines_discount: entry.coupon_lines.discount,
  coupon_lines_discount_tax: entry.coupon_lines.discount_tax,
});

// format json to jsonl
const format = async (message) => {
  let jsonl;
  try {
    // extract only the necessary

    const jsonMessage = await JSON.parse(message);

    const rows = await jsonMessage.map((row) => {
      const extractedRow = extract(row);
      return `${JSON.stringify(extractedRow)}\n`;
    });
    // join all lines as one string with no join symbol
    jsonl = rows.join('');

    console.log(jsonl);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('jsonl conversion failed');
  }
  return jsonl;
};

exports.jsonToBq = async (event, context) => {
  const message = Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString();
  const { filename } = event.attributes;

  console.log(filename);

  const jsonl = await format(message, filename);
  toBucket(jsonl, filename);
};
```

Comment: @Fract can you give a small example. I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's fixed by moving the bufferstream const into the tobucket function.